# Toggling a conditional variable in Python seems redundant, must be a better way

Tags: python

I often have variables to track if some code should be run or already has run, toggling them seems redundant, but I can't figure out a tighter way to write it

```
if thishour != datetime.now(TZ).hour:
    thishour = datetime.now(TZ).hour
    print("=" * 13)
    print(str(thishour - 12 if thishour > 12 else thishour) + " o'clock")
    print("-" * 13)
```

It just seems like the first two lines could be cleaned up as they are almost identical, so each time I write an if statement like this it drives me nuts, but I can't think how to make it cleaner.

Comment: Side note: `thishour - 12 if thishour > 12 else thishour` could also be written as `(thishour - 1) % 12 + 1`. Though the existing version may be more readable

Comment: Sidenote: You can simplify that string formatting by either using an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals): `print(f"{thishour-12 if thishour>12 else thishour} o'clock")` or having `print` call `str` for you and add a space: `print(thishour-12 if thishour>12 else thishour, "o'clock")`.

Comment: @Brian61354270: Your version is actually more correct if you're trying to stick to typical 1-12 hours, AM/PM style. As written by the OP, midnight will be displayed as hour 0 (while noon is 12); your solution displays both as 12.

Comment: @Brian61354270: Another approach that works for this scenario in Python is `thishour % 12 or 12`. This works because Python's `or` always returns the last thing evaluated (so, the first truthy value, or the last value regardless of truthiness), and treats `0` as falsy; for any hour that's not `0` or `12`, `thishour % 12` gets the correct answer. `0` and `12` both reduce to the falsy `0`, so the `or` replaces that `0` with `12`. In other languages (where `0` is truthy, or `or` returns bools, not the last evaluated operand) your version is better, this version is just a little simpler in Python.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was just about to say the same thing about midnight :) Another option is to keep a reference to `datetime.now(TZ)` and do `.strftime('%I').lstrip('0')` or [use a platform-specific format spec](/a/2073189/4518341).

Answer (score 3):

Generally the ideal solution is to expand those two lines to three, to avoid repeating yourself:

```
currenthour = datetime.now(TZ).hour
if thishour != currenthour:
    thishour = currenthour
    ...
```

You *can* condense that down to two lines again with the walrus "operator", `:=`, but it's moderately ugly, and the separate lines are more readable:

```
if thishour != (currenthour := datetime.now(TZ).hour):
    thishour = currenthour
    ...
```

Either way, it's better than your current solution, as it avoids needlessly querying for the current time and constructing `datetime` objects twice.